# When drawing function, compute $f',~f''$ first or vertical asymptotic first?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, asymptotics, graphing-functions

In Calculus, some functions don't have vertical asymptotics (e.g. $f(x)=2x+\cos x$), while some functions, say $f(x)=x+1/x$, may have vertical asymptotics. In the former case, we just compute $f'$ and $f''$ as always. However, in the latter case, some teachers tend to compute vertical asymptotic **before** computing $f'$ and $f''$, which interrupt the habit that students accustomed to earlier. So the natural question to ask here, which thing to compute first is better? Any concrete example is welcomed.

Comment: This seems like it would be a better fit for the math educators SE site.

Comment: I think it is more closely to mathematics itself, because I'm seeking a mathematical reason that computing vertical asymptotic first is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

People generally check for vertical asymptotes first because a vertical asymptote can immediately and easily be sketched into a graph. Also the location of vertical asymptotes can help flesh out the meaning of derivatives.

On the other hand, if we started with derivatives, they might imply asymptotes but we would probably still want to check for asymptotes before graphing.

Comment: I see. But even a vertical asymptote can immediately and easily be sketched into a graph (say we know that at $3$, we have $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\infty$, which means there is an unbounded above behavior around $3$), without knowing $f'$, we can not know what the curve looks like (extremum, increasing, etc) far from $3$.

Comment: Yes, the asymptote won't tell you much beyond the fact that there's an asymptote. But they're still important features for a graph that can be quickly incorporated into sketching the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

If in the denominator some terms are noticeable which go to zero then compute roots (called poles) of that term *at first*, to fix the column in which your curve can fit in.

*Next* setting derivative of $f(x)$ to zero find corresponding max/min values. Look to $x$ values when $y=0$ or $y$ values when $x=0$.

When sketching curve in area between asymptotes choose $x$ values to fill in U shaped deep cups and humps with steep cliffs.